# How to open google drive public link

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have uploaded a file on google drive, i have made it public. i am able to access this on browser but not with my android app.
I need to access this public link on MY ANDROID APP.
PFB the link of file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56C1LC3IVXCV055WFIyVTZjTTA/edit?usp=docslist_api
Is this possible to access a publicly shared GD file on android app?

Code snippet is

```
URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56C1LC3IVXCV055WFIyVTZjTTA/edit?usp=docslist_api");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
return bmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to format the address of the document you have shared.

Check this :

```
URL = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + IDFile + "&export=download";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about scaling the picture down to a reasonable size, it may just be that the image is too large for your heap to load

`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int Width, int Height, boolean filter)`

Comment: Image size is about 120kb, This is not big size.? https://s3.amazonaws.com/prod.tracker2/resource/47529028/hey_big.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIKWOAN6H4H3QMJ6Q&Expires=1436170027&Signature=NI0r61zldvgJ1Mp1dKSKE6Ex2c8%3D this open link is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is not to image but to Google Drive App with this image opened, real URL to image is [this](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/iR2-Em-EbdLoGSF8OGzxXlaclNqlAWYHBoKL6-FE0QC8tJKQ9iNGUqwQqUSLFw5MKxh03r0osp0w7Ao=w1246-h569)

Consider using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started)

Comment: Can we access without google drive api? google drive apis has so many issues.

Comment: My question is, Can i access this public URL yes or no? because i am able to access in browser. –

Comment: In this case the only way is to parse HTML and get value of src attribute of <img> tag contatining photo

Answer (score 0):

There one other way to access file's public link By adding :

```
https://googledrive.com/host/[folderId]/fileName.extension
```

As you have provide file url

You can use that url like this for public access

```
https://googledrive.com/host/0B56C1LC3IVXCV055WFIyVTZjTTA
```

Comment: My question is, Can i access this public URL yes or no? becuse i am able to access in browser.

Comment: yo want to know if you can access it in javascript?

Comment: I want to know, Can i access this in android app or not? because in web browser its possible to access.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56C1LC3IVXCV055WFIyVTZjTTA/edit?usp=docslist_api this is the link. I am not able to open image in andorid but it is possible in web browser.

Comment: you can access this file by this link :> https://googledrive.com/host/0B56C1LC3IVXCV055WFIyVTZjTTA

Comment: https://googledrive.com/host/0B56C1LC3IVXCV055WFIyVTZjTTA This is not woking but after click url a new URL generated . this is not working in andorid.

Comment: after click above link a new click is created that is working for me in andorid.

Comment: I think you should consider using Google client api.

Comment: I want to access all file in my andorid app which is create from web.drive but this does not allow me to access all the file has been created from web.drive. I can access only those file has been created by app. Thanks

Comment: You can do pretty much everything by client api

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get there are lots off example here

Comment: If i am not wrong then it allows only those file and folder to access which is created from app not web. If a folder is created having five files from web then it will not be access able using these api.

Comment: It could just simply be that your link needs you to be logged in with your google account since that may be why you were able to open the link on the web and not in your app. You should consider using the Google Drive API or Google Play Services Library to log the user in before he opens the picture. Or better still, just use another image client like a file hosting site that does not require log in info.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to grab the webContentLink of the newly created file.

From the documentation ...

**webContentLink**  string
A link for downloading the content of the file in a browser using cookie based authentication. In cases where the content is shared publicly, the content can be downloaded without any credentials.